# Plotting and handling horizontal space of multiple boxplots from file

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I want to plot several boxplots together but I have a couple of problems.

[image]

1. Each 5 boxplots belong to the same condition, that's why they have the same style (crappy, at the moment, but I'm gonna work on it later :D).
   As you might notice, at the moment, when a block of 5 boxplots is plotted, the following one comes directly after on the x axis.
   I'd like to find a way to add some space between each block of 5 boxplots in order to visually separate them.
   I know that there is the command `draw position` but if I include that each set of 5 boxplots is plotted in the same position (I commented the code to get this result in the MWE), 
   [image]while I'd still like to keep some little space between them (I left this "bad" approach in one of the comments).
   Ideally, I'd like to have control on the spacing between and within sets of boxplots.
2. Additionally, is there a way to loop the `filename` in a smarter way? In this dummy example I only have 3 sets of data, but in reality I have more than 3 files. Perhaps using a variable to store the filenames would be better?

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{audio1.tsv}
37  22  79  3   100
9   60  113 1   97
29  63  65  0   99
12  21  83  0   99
7   28  78  1   97
29  -10 73  1   98
17  32  73  1   98
10  58  78  0   95
17  45  73  2   99
38  28  91  0   96
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{speech4.tsv}
17  47  97  0   95
3   53  103 1   97
37  70  104 1   99
21  41  109 0   100
36  53  86  3   98
37  58  90  3   99
8   30  81  1   97
19  44  99  4   96
20  20  118 3   96
27  2   107 3   99
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{music3.tsv}
26  -5  79  4   100
12  61  101 0   99
13  32  116 1   98
10  17  94  3   93
9   81  75  4   100
7   50  58  0   98
30  56  79  2   99
19  28  93  1   92
10  31  49  1   99
11  22  46  0   100
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%/*
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
    {color=red},
    {color=green},
    {color=blue},
    {color=magenta},
    {color=black}
}
\pgfplotsset{% General options
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    cycle list name=mycolorlist,
    boxplot/draw direction=y,xmin=0,xmax=30
}
%       
\begin{groupplot}[ 
    group style={
    group name=myplot,
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=0pt,
    horizontal sep=0pt,
    },
]
\nextgroupplot[
    xlabel={sdasdas},   
]
  \foreach \filename in {audio1,speech4,music3} {
    \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
             % draw each originally row, now column as boxplot
             % \addplot+ [boxplot={draw position=5*\i}] table [y index=\i] {\filename.tsv};
             \addplot+ [boxplot] table [y index=\i] {\filename.tsv};
     }
 }
\end{groupplot}
%*/
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you mean something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\begin{filecontents}{audio1.tsv}
37  22  79  3   100
9   60  113 1   97
29  63  65  0   99
12  21  83  0   99
7   28  78  1   97
29  -10 73  1   98
17  32  73  1   98
10  58  78  0   95
17  45  73  2   99
38  28  91  0   96
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{speech4.tsv}
17  47  97  0   95
3   53  103 1   97
37  70  104 1   99
21  41  109 0   100
36  53  86  3   98
37  58  90  3   99
8   30  81  1   97
19  44  99  4   96
20  20  118 3   96
27  2   107 3   99
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{music3.tsv}
26  -5  79  4   100
12  61  101 0   99
13  32  116 1   98
10  17  94  3   93
9   81  75  4   100
7   50  58  0   98
30  56  79  2   99
19  28  93  1   92
10  31  49  1   99
11  22  46  0   100
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        groupplots,
        statistics,
    }
    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
        {color=red},
        {color=green},
        {color=blue},
        {color=magenta},
        {color=black}
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.10,
        width=8cm,
        height=5cm,
        cycle list name=mycolorlist,
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 2,
        },
        xmin=0,
        xmax=25,
        xlabel={sdasdas},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        % add here another variable so we can use it for calculations
        \foreach \filename/\j in {
            audio1/1,
            speech4/2,
            music3/3%
        } {
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
                % draw each originally row, now column as boxplot
                \addplot+ [
                    boxplot={
                        % now calculate the positions depending on how they
                        % should be organized
                        draw position=5*\i+\j,
                    }
                ] table [y index=\i] {\filename.tsv};
            }
        }
    \nextgroupplot
        % add here another variable so we can use it for calculations
        \foreach \filename/\j in {
            audio1/1,
            speech4/2,
            music3/3%
        } {
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
                % draw each originally row, now column as boxplot
                \addplot+ [
                    boxplot={
                        % now calculate the positions depending on how they
                        % should be organized
                        draw position=7*(\j-1) + \i+1,
                    }
                ] table [y index=\i] {\filename.tsv};
            }
        }
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: `\foreach \filename/\j `is new to me :) So you can use `/` and `pgfplots`or `pgf/tikz` understand that syntax. Crazy.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, yes, but in PGFPlots this currently is limited to 2 "variables" whereas in TikZ you can use more (don't know if there is a limit and where it is).

Comment: Well, that's way easier than I thought :) 
Anyway, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @gbernardi, you are welcome.